# Copy instead of insert lines in excel VB

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently running the below script

```
Sub Gift_Certificate()

    'Select Bridge Data from tab, cell A2
    Sheets("Bridge Data").Select
    Range("A2").Select

    'Loop while activecell is not blank (goes down the column)
    Do While ActiveCell <> ""
        'Repeat below step if data needs to be sorted into multiple wksts'
        '  Also, create individual worksheets for each
        If InStr(1, ActiveCell, "Gift Certificate", 1) <> 0 Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("GC Redeemed").Select
            Range("A10").Select

        Else
            'If it's not an extension you have specified, it highlites the cell because its cool'
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            GoTo SKIPPING
        End If

        Range("A10").Select
        'Loops down until there's an open cell'
        Do While ActiveCell <> ""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop

        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

        'Go back to the starting sheet & iterate to the next row
        Sheets("Bridge Data").Select
SKIPPING:
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

I'm using it to scan through data on one tab and copy select data onto another tab.  The problem I'm running into is that I'd like to run formulas off the newly pasted data however when the script runs it inserts the new lines into the tab, pushing all of my formulas down.

I'd like to just have the script copy the data into the new tab, instead of an insert.

Any advice?

ps, I have next to zero experience in vb, so please take it easy on me!

Thanks,

-Sean

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very different approach that uses filtering to select the range that meets your criteria and copies it to the end of the target sheet.  I'm not sure how it will affect your formula requirements, but give it a try:

```
Sub Gift_Certificate()
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim TargetNextRow As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bridge Data")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GC Redeemed")
'Find the next empty row in the target sheet
With wsTarget
    TargetNextRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With
With wsSource
    'Find the last filled row in the source sheet
    SourceLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Turn off any Autofilters in case they are in other columns
    'I think this is the best way to handle this
    If .AutoFilterMode Then
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    'Filter to non-matching, and fill with yellow
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Gift Certficate*", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("A2:A" & SourceLastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    'Filter to matching and copy to target sheet
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Gift Certficate*", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("A2:A" & SourceLastRow).EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _
                                                  wsTarget.Range("A" & TargetNextRow)
'Turn off autofilter
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```